# Empty .png output for matplotlib plotting in submodules

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a Python module that requires that I generate about 24 different figures. To clear up the code, I put the individual plotting functions for the six or so groups of subplots into separate submodules and call them with the arrays they need for plotting purposes.

The structure of each individual one is along the lines of:

```
import os, numpy, scipy

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot(array1, array2):

    Initial Plotting Setup

    plt.clf()

    Plotting and saving commands
```

I import all of the plotting submodules at the head of the top module, and when I do this the only plot that gets generated is the one produced by the last plotting submodule imported. The rest are all blank .png files. I rearranged the import order, and that's how it worked. When I had it in the body of the top module, importing when it was time to plot, something similar happened.

Does anybody know why this might be happening, and how I can fix it while keeping all my plotting tools in submodules?

Comment: You'll probably need to provide a bit more info to get a clear answer. Are you creating individual figures? or are you using the procedural interface through pyplot: plt.plot(),plt.savefig(), etc?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the procedural interface through pyplot. Here's an example:

`def varPlot(passCount, corrMat, plotsPlace):

    plt.clf()

    PLOTTING FUNCTIONS HERE

    pltname = "/variances.png"
    fname = plotsPlace + pltname
    fig.savefig(fname)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how do you organized your code. This works:

m1.py

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot():
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot([10,2,30,4])
    plt.title("m1")
    plt.savefig('m1')
```

m2.py

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot():
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
    plt.title("m2")
    plt.savefig('m2')
```

par.py

```
import m1
import m2

m1.plot()
m2.plot()
```

folder structure:

```
folder\
....__init__
....m1.py
....m2.py
....par.py
```

you run:

```
>> from folder import par
```

---

m1.png

[image]

m2.png

[image]

Comment: That's exactly the structure I have, and it is returning empty .png files for the plotting done in m1.

Comment: Is it **exactly** the same? do you still obtain an empty figure if you exactly reproduce my structure and files ?

Comment: I figured it out. I was using some definition as fig = plt.figure() that I got off the matplotlib website, and it was having some unintended consequences.

The real lesson here is to not use fig = plt.figure()...

Comment: No, you can use `plt.figure` but then you have to code accordingly.

Comment: @webb please don't forget to select the answer if it was of help